# POST/PATCH works in LoopBack Explorer but not Postman

Tags: node.js, rest, http-post, loopback, http-patch

I am building an Angular app that uses a REST API built from NodeJS and LoopBack.  When trying to create new records, I'm getting a weird error both from my app and also in Postman. (Property names have been changed to protect the innocent)

```
The `ObjectName` instance is not valid. 
Details: `id` can't be blank (value: undefined); 
`property2` can't be blank (value: undefined); 
`property3` can't be blank (value: undefined).
```

This is what I have posted:

```
{
    "id":0,
    "property2":"foo",
    "property3":"bar",
    "property4":"R"
}
```

The weirdest part of this is that when I try to run this through the LoopBack API Explorer, it works just fine.  I have the same issues with PATCH methods as well.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: how are sending data via post man can you post a screen shot or something

Comment: @RahulSingh I am sending it in the body tab, with the 'raw' option selected.  That is how I have always sent json data with Postman.  I cannot post a screenshot because I do not have a way to blur sensitive data.

Comment: @ChrisHampton: Did you set headers (`Content-Type`, `Accept`)? When you make a request via LoopBack API Explorer, it also generates a curl command. Does that curl command work for you?

Comment: @IvanSchwarz I've set the headers in Postman as well as in my angular app, but I get the same error.  Incidentally, the curl command works just fine.  Go figure...

Comment: @ChrisHampton: If you open network tab in chrome dev tools, is there any difference between the request made by API Explorer/curl and the request made by Postman/your app?

Comment: @IvanSchwarz No, there wasn't.  However, I have found the cause.  Please see my comment below.

Comment: @ChrisHampton Well, you just wrote in your answer, that the request is different. You were sending a different JSON object in your Angular app. Anyway, LoopBack shouldn't return this kind of Error if you add extra properties. I'm not able to reproduce that. I also still don't understand why postman didn't work but curl and API Explorer did for identical requests. I'm glad that you solved your issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. In previous APIs I have worked with, the back-end was set up with a model binder that would apply the properties it needed and discard the ones it did not.  So I have typically send the entire object in POSTs/PUTs/etc.  In this case, we do not have that, so it was throwing this weird error.  Once I added a method to my Angular auto-mapper that would strip the object down to only the bare necessities, it worked just fine.

In the end, I could have figured that out if the error message had been better.